# Apple Music Carousel Not Responding to Button Clicks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been working on creating an Apple Music-style carousel with "Previous" and "Next" buttons in my web application. The carousel appears correctly, and the buttons are being clicked without any errors in the console. However, the carousel isn't moving when the buttons are clicked. I would greatly appreciate any guidance on what might be causing this issue.

**Javascript function
**

```
   /*playlist carousel*/
   `const Grid = () => {
   const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

  const sounds = [
   "https://embed.music.apple.com/us/album/in-between-and-overseas/1607100188?i=1607101242",
   "https://embed.music.apple.com/us/album/orange-village/1677236538?i=1677236904",
   "https://embed.music.apple.com/us/album/dreams-money-can-buy/1475177816?i=1475177817",
   "https://embed.music.apple.com/us/album/goyard-umbrella/1677198478?i=1677198491",
   "https://embed.music.apple.com/us/album/louis-baggage-feat-babyface-ray/1609125563?i=1609126175",
   "https://embed.music.apple.com/us/album/east-liberty/1662164512?i=1662164513",
   "https://embed.music.apple.com/us/album/ive-been-daydreaming-my-entire-life/1243853548?      i=1243853559",
    ];

// Defining Back and Forth Functions

  const handlePrev = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((currentIndex - 1 + sounds.length) % sounds.length);
 }


 const handleForward = () => {
  setCurrentIndex((currentIndex + 1) % sounds.length);
}`
```

**Code**

`

Current Rotation

```
              </div>
              <div className='flex w-auto gap-4 '> 
              {sounds.map((slide, index) => (
                  <iframe 
                    allow="autoplay *; encrypted-media *; fullscreen *; clipboard-write"
                    width="100%"  // Use responsive width
                    height="200"
                    key={index}
                    style={{ maxWidth: '500px', maxHeight:'500px', overflow: 'hidden', borderRadius: '10px' }}
                    src= {slide}
                  >
                  </iframe>
              )) }
              </div>
              {/* forward & previous button */}
              <div className='w-full h-auto flex gap-72 justify-center'>
                    <button onClick={handlePrev} className='w-8 h-8 hover:bg-white/20 rounded-full flex items-center justify-center transition ease-in duration-800 animate-carousel-left'><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronLeft} style={{color: "#ffffff", fontSize: '16px'}} /></button>
                    <button onClick={handleForward} className='w-8 h-8 hover:bg-white/20 rounded-full flex items-center justify-center transition ease-in duration-800 animate-carousel-right'><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronRight} style={{color: "#ffffff", fontSize: '16px'}} /></button>
              </div>
            </div>`
```

**KeyFrames**

```
"carousel-left": {
      from: {
        transform:
          "translateX(-10px)" /* Start position (off-screen to the left) */,
        opacity: "0",
      },
      to: {
        transform:
          "translateX(0px)" /* End position (off-screen to the left) */,
        opacity: "1",
      },
    },
    "carousel-right": {
      from: {
        transform:
          "translateX(10px)" /* Start position (off-screen to the right) */,
        opacity: "0",
      },
      to: {
        transform:
          "translateX(0px)" /* End position (off-screen to the right) */,
        opacity: "1",
      },
    },
```

My goal is to have the next and previous button work